# Kinetic JS - Put length of a line on top of it

Tags: kineticjs

I am calculating the length of a line that I draw on the canvas using the following:

```
layer.on("mouseup", function () {
                moving = false;
                var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
                x2 = mousePos.x;
                y2 = mousePos.y;
                $("#distance").val(calculateDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2));

            });
function calculateDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            var distance = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
            distance *= 0.264583333;
            distance = Math.round(distance * 100 / 1) / 100;
            return distance;
}
```

currently I am putting the distance in an input field; however I would like to add it as a lable for the line! Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/xzEad/1/.

I would appreciate your suggetions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a midpoint and a label. Customize this to fit your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/xzEad/2/

```
            var midX = (line.getPoints()[0].x + line.getPoints()[1].x)/2;
            var midY = (line.getPoints()[0].y + line.getPoints()[1].y)/2;
            var label = new Kinetic.Text({
                x: midX,
                y: midY,
                text: calculateDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2),
                fontSize: 20,
                fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                fill: 'green'
            });
            layer.add(label);
            layer.draw();
```